# WPF bind Combobox-properties to different Datasources

Tags: wpf, combobox, selectedindex

I want to understand how I can set different bindingsources to a combobox. For example:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        customers cs = new customers();
        itcModels.ItemsSource = cs.list;
    }
}

public class CarModels
{
    public ObservableCollection<car> list { get; set; }
    public CarModels()
    {
        list = new ObservableCollection<car>();
        list.Add(new car() { model = "Porsche" });
        list.Add(new car() { model = "BMW" });
        list.Add(new car() { model = "Audi" });
        list.Add(new car() { model = "Mercedes" });
    }
}
public class car
{
    public string model { get; set; }
}
public class customers
{
    public ObservableCollection<customer> list { get; set; }
    public customers()
    {
        list = new ObservableCollection<customer>();
        list.Add(new customer() { hisCar = 3 });
        list.Add(new customer() { hisCar = 1 });
        list.Add(new customer() { hisCar = 2 });
        list.Add(new customer() { hisCar = 0 });
    }
}
public class customer
{
    public int hisCar { get; set; }
}
```

CustomControlCustomer.xaml

```
<Grid>
    <ComboBox x:Name="cboCustomerCar" ItemsSource="{Binding list}" DisplayMemberPath="model"/>
</Grid>
```

CustomControlCustomer.cs

```
 public partial class ccCustomer : UserControl
{
    public ccCustomer()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        cboCustomerCar.DataContext = new CarModels();

    }
}
```

I'd like to do the following:
1. bind the combobox-list to the CarModels.list so that all the models are in the list (already done within the code)
2. set (or better:) bind the selected index of each combobox to each customer.hiscar

Any Idea how I could do that?

Comment: I am not 100% clear on what you are trying to do, seeing that the XAML code presented does not contain the customer control. You want to be able to select a customer, and then change the type of car he has from another  combobox with car models?

Comment: What I want to do is to have the combobox filled with the car models from the CarModels.iist and then the selected index of the combobox should be set by the (int) customer.hisCar

Comment: Can you have both lists in the same ViewModel? Or is it mandatory they remain in different ViewModels?

Comment: yes, I could add another class where put a reference to the customer and the CarModels and bind to it. I did that already in a test project and it worked well. But is that really the correct way to implement a situation like this correctly? For me it would be more "logic" to fill the combobox with some data from the responsible class and then set the selectedindex by each individual customer. When I implement it like mentioned before, it needs more (maybe unnecessary)  resources

Comment: You should create a view model where you store both the collection of selectable items *and* the currently selected item. Customers is a (rather unnecessary) type that simply wraps a collection of customer. The same thing with CarModels. You don't need these classes.